# Microsoft Excel chart with dynamic series

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2013

I am working on creating a excel template file that includes charts generated from the data added. One of the charts displays trending data over 12 months for an unknown number of products. The example below shows a piece of the 12 month breakdown against three products:

```
           Product A     Product B     Product C
6/1/2013        1588          3488          1391
7/1/2013        1821          3629          1460
8/1/2013        1857          3208          1598
9/1/2013        2601          2496          1325
...
```

I can easily create a chart with the existing data. However, if I want to add another column for a 4th product (Product D), I am unable to get the chart to automatically add it as a new series. Is this possible with Excel (I am currently using 2013)?

Thanks.

Comment: I think your only options would be to have a blank series already in there (it would show up in a legend it you had it but with no title), or a vba solution.

Answer (score 2):

This works fine in Excel 2010 (no guarantee for 2013, but it should work).

1. Convert your data to an Excel Table.
2. Create a Chart from your Excel Table and format to taste.
3. As you update your data (in the Excel Table), the Chart will automatically update as well.

   - If you add a row (new data for your existing products), your Series will be extended.
   - If you add a column (new product), your new product will be added to the Chart as a new Series.

[image: dynamic add series to chart]

Comment: Works in 2013 and so far the preview of 2016.